# Python urllib2 request error

Tags: python, urllib2

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 13 2014, 11:03:55)
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib2
>>> req = urllib2.Request("http:///wp-login.php")
>>> website='kseek.com.my'
>>> req = urllib2.Request("http://"+website+"/wp-login.php")
>>> req.add_header('User-agent', 'Mozilla 5.10')
>>> req.add_header('Referer', 'http://'+website)
>>> data = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=6).read()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 520, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 445, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 379, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 528, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 406: Not Acceptable
>>> req = urllib2.Request("http://"+website+"/")
>>> req.add_header('User-agent', 'Mozilla 5.10')
>>> req.add_header('Referer', 'http://'+website)
>>> data = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=6).read()
>>>
```

As you notice,
When requesting /wp-login.php which i can reach manually via browser ow even curl I get 406 error
while with the same method requesting /index.php , work without problem
Any help?

Comment: whats that??? req = urllib2.Request("http:///wp-login.php")

Comment: It is clearly unacceptable. :/ Aside from that, i don't know... :)

Comment: That was just mistake which have been corrected in the next line
and the problem was in the missing Accept header
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting [HTTP error 406](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E406.html) because you're missing the `Accept` header. Add the following before you open the URL:

```
req.add_header('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8')
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
>>> req.add_header('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8')
>>> data = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=6).read()
>>> print data
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--[if IE 8]>
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="ie8" lang="en-US">
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if !(IE 8) ]><!-->
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>K SEE K architect &rsaquo; Log In</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' id='buttons-css'  href='http://kseek.com.my/wp-includes/css/buttons.min.css?ver=4.2.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='open-sans-css'  href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans%3A300italic%2C400italic%2C600italic%2C300%2C400%2C600&#038;subset=latin%2Clatin-ext&#038;ver=4.2.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css'  href='http://kseek.com.my/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=4.2.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='login-css'  href='http://kseek.com.my/wp-admin/css/login.min.css?ver=4.2.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/wp-content/uploads/fbrfg/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/wp-content/uploads/fbrfg/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/wp-content/uploads/fbrfg/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/wp-content/uploads/fbrfg/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/wp-content/uploads/fbrfg/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/wp-content/uploads/fbrfg/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/wp-content/uploads/fbrfg/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/wp-content/uploads/fbrfg/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/wp-content/uploads/fbrfg/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/wp-content/uploads/fbrfg/favicon.ico">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/wp-content/uploads/fbrfg/favicon-192x192.png" sizes="192x192">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/wp-content/uploads/fbrfg/favicon-160x160.png" sizes="160x160">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/wp-content/uploads/fbrfg/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/wp-content/uploads/fbrfg/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/wp-content/uploads/fbrfg/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/wp-content/uploads/fbrfg/mstile-144x144.png">
<meta name="msapplication-config" content="/wp-content/uploads/fbrfg/browserconfig.xml"><meta name='robots' content='noindex,follow' />
    </head>
    <body class="login login-action-login wp-core-ui  locale-en-us">
    <div id="login">
        <h1><a href="https://wordpress.org/" title="Powered by WordPress" tabindex="-1">K SEE K architect</a></h1>

<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="http://kseek.com.my/wp-login.php" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="user_login">Username<br />
        <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="input" value="" size="20" /></label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="user_pass">Password<br />
        <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="input" value="" size="20" /></label>
    </p>
        <p class="forgetmenot"><label for="rememberme"><input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever"  /> Remember Me</label></p>
    <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button button-primary button-large" value="Log In" />
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="http://kseek.com.my/wp-admin/" />
        <input type="hidden" name="testcookie" value="1" />
    </p>
</form>

<p id="nav">
    <a href="http://kseek.com.my/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword" title="Password Lost and Found">Lost your password?</a>
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
function wp_attempt_focus(){
setTimeout( function(){ try{
d = document.getElementById('user_login');
d.focus();
d.select();
} catch(e){}
}, 200);
}

wp_attempt_focus();
if(typeof wpOnload=='function')wpOnload();
</script>

    <p id="backtoblog"><a href="http://kseek.com.my/" title="Are you lost?">&larr; Back to K SEE K architect</a></p>

    </div>


        <div class="clear"></div>
    </body>
    </html>

>>>
```

Comment: Thanks so much , It confused me that the index page loaded normally without any extra headers,
Thanks again